# Dynamic & Complex rowspan in HTML table from json array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html-table

I wanted to achieve similar result as shown in below image.

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Question: Looking for Jquery or javascript solution to create dynamic table along with Rowspan. I am facing issue to get the parent row and add the rowspan.

Your help is much appreciated.

Here is my JSON format and what I am trying to achieve:

```js
var data={"result": [
    {
      "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_ID": "20190402080337958516",
      "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_KODE": "02",
      "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail": [
        {
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_ID": "20190402080403561417",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH": "KUALA ENOK",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi": [
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190329144213331884",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "YANTO KHO",
            },
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190329144712243937",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "USMAN",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_ID": "20190402080355461744",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH": "ENOK",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi": [
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190329150712446114",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "NURDIN",
            },
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190329151404711228",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "H. HARUNA RASYID",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_ID": "20190402080411413459",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH": "PARIT PINANG",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi": [
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190329153052471217",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "SUWANDI",
            },
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190329153610274231",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "BEDDU",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_ID": "20190402080607764729",
      "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_KODE": "03",
      "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail": [
        {
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_ID": "20190402132520833736",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH": "PULAU KIJANG",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi": [
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190402132304152471",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "H. BAHARUDIN",
            },
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190402132622621585",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "HM. NUR HDP",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_ID": "20190402140031812644",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH": "BENTENG",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi": [
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190402135920441438",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "SURGAWI",
            },
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20200325091038411761",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "M. TANG",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_ID": "20190402140141611248",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH": "KOTA BARU",
          "RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi": [
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190402140121737955",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "H. RAMLI",
            },
            {
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20190402140908815557",
              "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "H. SYAMSUDDIN",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
function createRowHTML(){
          var record=''; 
     var record1Nya=''; 
     var record_detailNya='';
     
     var record1=[]; 
     var record_detail=[];
     
     var record1_relasi=[]; 
     var record_relasi_detail=[]; 
     
     var jlhRowRelasi=[];
     var jlhRowDetailWilayah=0;
     var jlhRowSpan=0;
          
     for(i=0;i<data.result.length;i++)
     {
      var jlhRowDetailWilayah=data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail.length;
      for(iDetail=0;iDetail<data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail.length;iDetail++)
      {
       jlhRowRelasi[i]=data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[iDetail].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi.length;
       for(iRelasi=0;iRelasi<data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[iDetail].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi.length;iRelasi++)
       {
        if(iRelasi==0)
        {
         record1_relasi[i] = record1_relasi[i]+"<td>"+
                   data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[iDetail].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi[iRelasi].RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA+
                 "</td>";
        }else
        {
         record_relasi_detail[i] = record_relasi_detail[i]+"<tr>"+
            "<td>"+
             data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[iDetail].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi[iRelasi].RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA+
            "</td>"+
           "</tr>";
        }
       }
       
       
       if(iDetail==0)
       {
        record1[i] = record1[i]+"<td rowspan='"+jlhRowRelasi[i]+"'>"+
             data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[iDetail].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH+
           "</td>"+record1_relasi[i];
       }else
       {
        record_detail[i] = record_detail[i]+"<tr>"+
           "<td rowspan='"+jlhRowRelasi[i]+"'>"+
            data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[iDetail].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH+
           "</td>"+
          "</tr>"+record_relasi_detail[i];
       }
      }
       
      record1Nya=record1[i];
      record_detailNya=record_detail[i];
      
    
      jlhRowSpan=parseInt(jlhRowDetailWilayah)+parseInt(jlhRowRelasi);
      record = record+"<tr>"+
           "<td rowspan='"+jlhRowSpan+"'>"+
            data.result[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_KODE+
           "</td>"+
           record1Nya+
          "</tr>"+record_detailNya;     
     }
     
     
     $("tbody#zone_data").html(record);
}
$(function(){
 createRowHTML();
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
     <td>Wil</td>
     <td>Lokasi</td>
     <td>Relasi</td>
         </tr>
    <tbody id="zone_data">
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

This is the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried solving your problem. Below are the changes in createRowHTML function.

```
function createRowHTML() {
    var tableContent = "";
    for (var result = 0; result < data.result.length; result++) {
        // calculate rowspan for first cell
        var rowspan = 0;
        var detailLength = data.result[result].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail.length;
        rowspan += detailLength;
        for (var i = 0; i < detailLength; i++) {
            rowspan += data.result[result].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi.length;
        }

        // create rows
        tableContent += "<tr><td rowspan=" + parseInt(1 + rowspan) + ">" + data.result[result].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_KODE + "</td></tr>";
        var relasiLength = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < detailLength; i++) {
            relasiLength = data.result[result].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi.length;
            tableContent += "<tr><td rowspan=" + parseInt(1 + relasiLength) + ">"
                + data.result[result].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH + "</td></tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < relasiLength; j++) {
                tableContent += "<tr><td>" + data.result[result].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_detail[i].RMP_MASTER_WILAYAH_relasi[j].RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA + "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    $("tbody#zone_data").append(tableContent);
}
$(function () {
    createRowHTML();
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/w8r2a9vs/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Amrita, this is very useful and cool.

Comment: With the same JSON format that I have written in the variable "data", please help once again if I want the following results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRLrr.png

Comment: I have done the changes in the fiddle example, here is the new link: http://jsfiddle.net/eh29kgmL/ I hope that is what you need.

Comment: You are so great..! With your help, I have found what I need. thanks.

Comment: Hello @Amrita , 
Sorry, I have trouble tagging you or asking questions directly from the chat, so I asked here.
Please provide a solution to my posts that are on  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63947998/3739963

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic of binary tree. For you problem can trace all nodes without children, on top parent, adding +1 to rowspan to any parent

in your example node without childrens

```
        {
          "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_ID": "20200325091038411761",
          "RMP_MASTER_PERSONAL_NAMA": "M. TANG",
        }
```

first parent receive 2 rowspan "points", next parent have summ of rowspans of his children

Algoritm:

1  traversal all nodes,

2 if finded node without childres travers all his parents and add +1 to "rowspan"

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I still can't make it.

Can you give an example of the javascript source code with the my JSON format that I have written in the variable "data"?